# Past tense with used to

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

This question has been puzzling me for the last two days

> He used to work as a doctor when I met him

Is this correct?

Comment: Perhaps "He was working as a doctor when I met him." Although that makes it seem as if the "doctor" is an imposter. "He was working at Hope Hospital when I met him."

Comment: Or just "He was a doctor when I met him."

Comment: More details please...  What do you think is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this sentence is fine.

However, it seems that are thinking that "used to" is some sort of combined phrase.  It is not.  The sentence breaks down into phrases like

```
    He     |  used  |  to work as a doctor   |   when I met him
 (subject) | (verb) | (prepositional clause) | (adverbial clause)
```

Yes, it is common to combine used with a prepositional phrase starting with "to", but it is not a requirement.

Comment: Sure it is.  See https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/used%20to

Answer (score 0):

*Used* to  can be used to talk about past habits which are no longer there.

> **He used to work as a doctor when I met him**

The sentence may be correct but it means that he is no longer a doctor now.

The sentence may connotate like this:

> **He used to work as a doctor when I met him but now I have come to know that he stopped practising as a doctor.**